# $E_{\theta_1}[\ell(\theta_2;X)] $

Tags: self-study, random-variable, inference, expected-value, likelihood

I am faced with the following in my "Statistical inference book"

$E_{\theta_1}[\ell(\theta_2;X)] $

where $\ell(\theta_2;X)$ (loglikelihood) is $\log [P(\theta_2;X)]$, X is a random variable.

What confuses me is taking expectations with an underlying parameter (in my case $\theta_1$  as in $E_{\theta_1} $) but what is $\theta_2$  in $\log[P(\theta_2;X)]$ isn't $\theta_2$ also an underlying parameter? I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

Let give you an example. Assume $x_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma),i=1,\ldots,n$ are i.i.d r.v. then

$$
l(\mu,\sigma)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-1}{2} (\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma})^2}
$$

then $E_\sigma (l(\mu,\sigma))$ is an example of what you are looking for and is

$$
E_\sigma (l(\mu,\sigma))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}l(\mu,\sigma)f(\sigma)d\sigma
$$